# scroll problem while clicking on TOC and the title goes behind header

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby

Currently, I'm using the smooth doc Gatsby theme and I saw that the theme has a scrolling issue. like when I click on the right-side TOC Link it scrolls to that topic and the theme as a sticky header so the scrolled h2 title goes behind that header... I tried to fix this problem but still not able to do that from my side.

can anybody please check the code and help me to fix this problem?
here is a component link that has code for this functionality also I have a demo link for your better understanding

[Demo link.. see on right side topic when we click on that the topic heading goes behind header](https://smooth-doc.com/docs/getting-started/#what-are-the-differences-with-other-documentation-generators)

[Code Link](https://github.com/gregberge/smooth-doc/blob/main/smooth-doc/src/components/TableOfContents.js)

```
    import React from 'react'
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved
import { useLocation } from '@reach/router'
import styled, { th } from '@xstyled/styled-components'

const TOP_OFFSET = 100

function getHeaderAnchors() {
  return Array.prototype.filter.call(
    document.getElementsByClassName('anchor'),
    (testElement) =>
      testElement.parentNode.nodeName === 'H2' ||
      testElement.parentNode.nodeName === 'H3',
  )
}

function getHeaderDataFromAnchor(el) {
  return {
    url: el.getAttribute('href'),
    text: el.parentElement?.innerText,
    depth: Number(el.parentElement?.nodeName.replace('H', '')),
  }
}

function getAnchorHeaderIdentifier(el) {
  return el?.parentElement?.id
}

export function useTocHighlight(ref) {
  const { pathname } = useLocation()
  const [lastActiveLink, setLastActiveLink] = React.useState(undefined)
  const [headings, setHeadings] = React.useState([])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setHeadings(getHeaderAnchors().map(getHeaderDataFromAnchor))
  }, [pathname])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let headersAnchors = []
    let links = []

    function setActiveLink() {
      function getActiveHeaderAnchor() {
        let index = 0
        let activeHeaderAnchor = null

        headersAnchors = getHeaderAnchors()
        while (index < headersAnchors.length && !activeHeaderAnchor) {
          const headerAnchor = headersAnchors[index]
          const { top } = headerAnchor.getBoundingClientRect()

          if (top >= 0 && top <= TOP_OFFSET) {
            activeHeaderAnchor = headerAnchor
          }

          index += 1
        }

        return activeHeaderAnchor
      }

      const activeHeaderAnchor = getActiveHeaderAnchor()

      if (activeHeaderAnchor) {
        let index = 0
        let itemHighlighted = false

        links = ref.current ? ref.current.querySelectorAll('a') : []

        while (index < links.length && !itemHighlighted) {
          const link = links[index]
          const { href } = link
          const anchorValue = decodeURIComponent(
            href.substring(href.indexOf('#') + 1),
          )

          if (getAnchorHeaderIdentifier(activeHeaderAnchor) === anchorValue) {
            if (lastActiveLink) {
              lastActiveLink.removeAttribute('aria-current')
            }

            link.setAttribute('aria-current', 'true')

            setLastActiveLink(link)
            itemHighlighted = true
          }

          index += 1
        }
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('scroll', setActiveLink)
    document.addEventListener('resize', setActiveLink)

    setActiveLink()

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', setActiveLink)
      document.removeEventListener('resize', setActiveLink)
    }
  })

  return headings
}

const TocContainer = styled.div`
  position: sticky;
  top: ${th.px(50)};
  padding: 5 0 4;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  font-size: 15;

  h4 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 13.5;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: on-background-light;
  }

  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;

    li {
      margin: 2 0;
      font-size: 14;

      &[data-depth='3'] {
        padding-left: 2;
      }
    }
  }

  a {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: fast;
    color: on-background-light;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.85;

    &[aria-current] {
      font-weight: 500;
      color: on-background;
      transform: translateX(2px);
      opacity: 1;
    }

    &:hover {
      color: on-background;
      transform: translateX(2px);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
`

export function TableOfContents() {
  const ref = React.useRef()
  const headings = useTocHighlight(ref)
  if (!headings.length) return null
  return (
    <TocContainer ref={ref}>
      <h4>On this page</h4>
      <ul>
        {headings.map((heading, i) =>
          heading.url ? (
            <li key={i} data-depth={heading.depth}>
              <a href={heading.url}>{heading.text}</a>
            </li>
          ) : null,
        )}
      </ul>
    </TocContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep header sticky or not??

Comment: yes header should be sticky

Comment: Oky, the only thing you want that h2 element should show infront of header. Right?

Comment: As far as I see, everything is fine. The only thing is that the header scroll to little below thats why title is hiding. And its intentional in the docs

Comment: i want that scroll should stop 1rem below the header so when we click on the right side TOC then the topic heading should be visible.. it should not goes behind header/navbar

Comment: Oky that can be acheive. let me update

Comment: do you have source code? Html code?? Paste here. I will update it

Comment: already provided repo link please find in post

Comment: That's not the right file. the file you attach has h4 tag. While in the documentation page, that you link, the title has h2 tag. Give specific page

Comment: it is the same file currently I'm using in my code base. i have cloned the official repo

Comment: do you got any solution

Comment: Because I don't find any code there. But if you have source code. I am going to write an answer with explanation. Just update it and try that

Comment: I have updated the code please check and confirm if is it the code you want

Comment: I have done that in my project. Let me show the script, implement on your project

Comment: I have added the code in the answer. Have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the code is working fine. The problem is that **header has position: sticky**. So, when we click on **a element**, it moves the page to specific heading div that has id. But due to sticky position of header, the header comes in front of the heading div.

Now to resolve the issue, you have to write a script. I have implemented the similar scenario of web page. Here is the code, try this:-

```js
const header = document.querySelector('header');
  const atag = document.querySelector('#heading1_a');
  const heading1 = document.querySelector('#heading1');

  atag.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    let target = e.currentTarget;
    let height = target.getBoundingClientRect().height; 
    window.scrollTo(0, heading1.offsetTop - height);
  })
```

```css
body{
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    header.parent_a{
      min-height: 100vh;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
    }

    header.parent_a a{
      display: block;
      background-color: rgb(163, 157, 157);
      padding: 1rem 1rem;
    }

    .parent_h1{
      min-height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
<header class="parent_a">
    <a id="heading1_a" href="#heading1">Move to Heading 1</a>
  </header>
  <div class="parent_h1">
    <h1 id="heading1">Heading 1</h1>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est iusto ratione temporibus officia possimus dolore ipsa nam necessitatibus nemo tempore sunt, earum ea voluptatem nostrum?</p>
```

Just implement the same logic. In your case, as there are 4 such a tags, so you can **use loop to bind click event to all the a element**.

Comment: let me try this

Comment: @GuruPawar Yes its working fine. Try this